# Registering users for instant messaging

Tags: android, contacts, messaging

I am planning for an application where the users has to register using their mobile number and they can communicate with their friends who uses the same app. I need to know what to do to make the application find if the users in the phone contacts have the same app?

Comment: You will need a server that will inform each user whom of his friends are using the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get a server
2. When a user signs up, register them on the server with their phone number
3. When another user signs up, register them, and then check their contacts with the numbers you already have registered.
4. If a number in their contacts matches one you have registered, then you have two users using the same app.
5. After that, use the server as a middle man in communicating between the two users.

Comment: Thanks @raghav . Now I have got an idea. After finding my friends, how to send a message to them? I don't want to use the inbuilt SMS service. I want to send message to them online like an instant messanger. Any ideas on where to get started on that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many ways to do that, the two most common being sending the message to the server from one device, and then pushing it from the server to the other, or using the server as a middle man to create the connection between two devices, and then directly sending the messages. The first one is more robust and less prone to losing messages

Comment: ok I got it. What kind of service should I use for that? I mean how to push the message to the server and push from the server to the users according to their phone number?

Comment: GCM would be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Find if the users contacts have the app?

Well you'll have to have a server to message, and that server will have a database.

Now this database will contain the information about the users including their numbers (or basically whatever fields you want).

Cross check against your database and you'll find who else has the app already.